# Sql Error: 2014: Commands out of sync in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-1.3

I have two stored procedure but when I call two stored procedure then the following error comes:

> Warning (512):
>
> SQL Error: 2014: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
>   [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 684]

I'm using cakephp.
And my code is:

```
$city=$this->City->query('call CityMaster_SelectCityName');
$allAgents=$this->Admin->query('call WorkForceLoginMaster_SelectLoginName(0)');
```

Is there a simple solution?

Answer (score 1):

When using stored procedures/prepared statements, you need to store the resultset before you can call another one. In raw mysqli, you'd use [mysqli_store_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php). I don't knw if Cake has any API for that though.

Comment: Thanks for reply but can you reply in some description. After your reply i use given code but my problem as it is: $city=$this->City->query('call CityMaster_SelectCityName', MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
$city->free();
$this->set('cities',$city);
$allAgents=$this->Admin->query('call WorkForceLoginMaster_SelectLoginName(0)');
$this->set('allAgents',$allAgents); After using this code error comes "Fatal error: Call to a member function free() on a non-object in /var/www/html/flatsnflats/app/controllers/inventorys_controller.php on line 18" Can you please guide me that how i use this.

Comment: I really don't know CakePHP. It looks like your `$city=$this->City->query('call CityMaster_SelectCityName', MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);` line did not return an object. Why I can't tell.

Comment: ok thanks sir,but can you tell me that how you use two stored procedures in **core php**.

Comment: Like I said, usually it's just a matter of calling `mysqli_store_result()` between calls to stored procs.